# Advanced JavaScript/HTML5 canvases

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, html5-canvas, prototype

I am learning about HTML5 (canvases) and advanced JavaScript (modules, prototypes, etc.) and would like to re-factor a basic snippet I have put together.

How can I reuse my function to work with multiple canvas elements on the same page? I found [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295346/multiple-canvas-in-the-browser-how-to-proceed) that describes the general idea I am hoping to achieve. However, I run into issues because I am calling my `draw()` method when I update an input on the page, which causes me to lose the context. Here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```js
var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

  win.onload = init;

  // canvas and context variables
  var canvas1, canvas2, canvas3;
  var context1, context2, context3;

  function init() {
    // draw the initial pattern
    drawPattern1();
    drawPattern2();
    drawPattern3();
  }


  // called whenever the slider value changes
  function drawPattern1() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('bullsEye1');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    const colors = ['#F00', '#00F'];
    const outerRadius = 50;
    let bandSize = doc.getElementById("bandWidth1").value;
    doc.getElementById("currentBandWidth1").innerHTML = bandSize;
    for (
      let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
    ) {
      context.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }

  function drawPattern2() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('bullsEye2');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    const colors = ['#F00', '#00F'];
    const outerRadius = 50;
    let bandSize = doc.getElementById("bandWidth2").value;
    doc.getElementById("currentBandWidth2").innerHTML = bandSize;
    for (
      let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
    ) {
      context.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }

  function drawPattern3() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('bullsEye3');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    const colors = ['#F00', '#00F'];
    const outerRadius = 50;
    let bandSize = doc.getElementById("bandWidth3").value;
    doc.getElementById("currentBandWidth3").innerHTML = bandSize;
    for (
      let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
    ) {
      context.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }

  return {
    drawPattern1: drawPattern1,
    drawPattern2: drawPattern2,
    drawPattern3: drawPattern3
  };

})(window, document);
```

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Bulls Eye</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="left">
      <canvas id="bullsEye1" style="border: 1px solid;">                  </canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth1">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth1" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern1()"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth1"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <canvas id="bullsEye2" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth2">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth2" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern2()"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth2"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <canvas id="bullsEye3" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth3">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth3" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern3()"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth3"></span></p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </main>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use objects, create a class with your functions and then instantiate an object to use it's functions.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking. I'm not quite there with my JavaScript yet though. This gives me some direction though. Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you :

```js
     var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

            win.onload = init;

            // canvas and context variables
            var canvas1, canvas2, canvas3;
            var context1, context2, context3;

            function init() {
                // draw the initial pattern
                drawPattern(1);
                drawPattern(2);
                drawPattern(3);
            }


            // called whenever the slider value changes

            function drawPattern(num) {
                const canvas = document.getElementById('bullsEye'+num);
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = 100;
                canvas.height = 100;

                const colors = ['#F00', '#00F'];
                const outerRadius = 50;
                let bandSize = doc.getElementById("bandWidth"+num).value;
                doc.getElementById("currentBandWidth"+num).innerHTML = bandSize;
                for (
                    let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
                ) {
                    context.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fill();
                }
            }

            return {
                drawPattern
            };

        })(window, document);
```

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Bulls Eye</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="left">
      <canvas id="bullsEye1" style="border: 1px solid;">                  </canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth1">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth1" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern(1)"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth1"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <canvas id="bullsEye2" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth2">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth2" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern(2)"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth2"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <canvas id="bullsEye3" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth3">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth3" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern(3)"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth3"></span></p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </main>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks good, what would the difference between your example and [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272167/8473614) be?

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework you should be doing yourself?
I won't rewrite so you'll get an A, but here's something to show get you going...

```js
var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

  win.onload = init;

  // canvas and context variables
  var canvas1, canvas2, canvas3;
  var context1, context2, context3;

  function init() {
    // draw the initial pattern
    draw('bullsEye1',doc.getElementById('bandWidth1').value, 'currentBandWidth1');
    draw('bullsEye2',doc.getElementById('bandWidth2').value, 'currentBandWidth2');
    draw('bullsEye3',doc.getElementById('bandWidth3').value, 'currentBandWidth3');
  }
  function draw(can,val, outid){
    const canvas=doc.getElementById(can);
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const output=doc.getElementById(outid)
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    const colors = ['#F00', '#00F'];
    const outerRadius = 50;
    let bandSize = val;
    output.innerHTML = bandSize;
    for (
      let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
    ) {
      context.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }



  return {
    draw:draw
  };

})(window, document);
```

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Bulls Eye</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="left">
      <canvas id="bullsEye1" style="border: 1px solid;">                  </canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth1">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth1" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.draw('bullsEye1',this.value,'currentBandWidth1')"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth1"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <canvas id="bullsEye2" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth2">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth2" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.draw('bullsEye2',this.value,'currentBandWidth2')"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth2"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <canvas id="bullsEye3" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas><br>
      <label for="bandWidth3">BandWidth:</label>
      <input type="range" id="bandWidth3" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.draw('bullsEye3',this.value,'currentBandWidth3')"></input>
      <p>Current band width: <span id="currentBandWidth3"></span></p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </main>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm busted! I thought I had a pretty good start on it but I was looking for some direction on how to refactor, not necessarily looking for the work to be done for me. I probably should have clarified what help I was looking for. Nonetheless, thank you for the quick reply!